# ZXing-cpp can't decode image

Tags: zxing

I'm interest in extracting barcode image. And I'm using ZXing C++ Port from https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing-cpp.

But when I build with cmake and run with all barcodes which ZXing support, only 8/15 barcodes can be decoded, including:
Code 39, Code 93, Code 128, ITF, Codabar, Aztec, UPC-A and UPC-E

The remaining barcodes: QR Code, Data Matrix, PDF 417, EAN-8, EAN-13, RSS-14 and  RSS Expanded can't be decoded.

And I don't know why, while with the same barcodes, I test in ZXing home page (online) from: http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx, all barcodes are decoded normally.

Anyone has been met as same as me? Or if you know why, please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking for an up-to-date c++ port of ZXing, you might want to give https://github.com/nu-book/zxing-cpp a try. It can decode all the mentioned codes and do that more reliably and faster than the original Java upstream project.